# how to add color inside a 3d chart in highchart js

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am using 3d option enabled scatter type highchart, now i want to color inner 3d area with two different colors, say red and blue. So my question is 
1. How to fill color inside a 3d area?
2. If filled, how to split that inner 3d area into two and add two different color?

my code is

```
var chartClassification = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'containerClassification',
    margin: 20,
    type: 'scatter',
    options3d: {
        enabled: true,
        alpha: 10,
        beta: 30,
        depth: 250,
        viewDistance: 5,
        fitToPlot: false,
        frame: {
            bottom: { size: 10, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)' },
            back: { size: 100, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.04)' },
            side: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.06)' }
        }
    }
},
title: {
    text: 'Classification'
},
plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        depth: 10
    }
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    title: null
},
xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    gridLineWidth: 1
},
zAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    showFirstLabel: false
},
legend: {
    enabled: false
},
series: [{
    name: 'Reading',
    color: 'black',
    data: []
}]
```

});

Comment: Can you create fiddle/demo for this ? also please put sample image of chart/drawing for expected output you want of chart.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate what you are asking about:

https://jsfiddle.net/cnxwue7k/

It's fairly easy to change the colors of each 3d area

just change the colors in the frame object:

```
frame: {
        bottom: { size: 10, color: 'grey' },
        back: { size: 100, color: 'red' },
        side: { size: 1, color: 'blue' }
    }
```

further info here:

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/3d-charts

Hope that helps :-D

Let me know if you need any more help

EDIT:

As [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6368761/d-paul) pointed out below in the comments, you can also add more colored axis which gives the desired effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/g6jhvcd2/

Comment: Jonathan, Thankyou for your reply. You have shown how to give color to each sides of a 3-d graph. What I am looking for is to color inside 3d area, which means, as the 3d box is cubical in shape and we plot points inside that cubical area, now a want to color that whole cubicl region, say something like colored jelly which is 3d in shape and has color.

Comment: some thing that will look like this                              https://www.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/3d-rendered-illustration-cross-section-water-194599778

Comment: I'm not sure it's achievable with highcharts though

You can make it draggable so it's a bit more interactive:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/

I don't think they have options to color the rest of the cube though

Comment: In addition to what Jonathan wrote, you can add more than one axis of x and y type. Take a look at the updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g6jhvcd2/.

Comment: Thankyou Jonathan and paul, is there any other js lib that I can use to make this possible? As i tried using canvasjs, but I felt even that wont serve the purpose.

Comment: Highcharts is definitely up there though https://blog.sicara.com/compare-best-javascript-chart-libraries-2017-89fbe8cb112d